# Read registry value in wix

Tags: wix

Hi all i am new to wix tool can any one help me to read the registry key variable value to another variable. Is there is any way to see the value contains in that variable in wix. Sample code is very much helpfull for me.

Thanks,
rajeev kumar.

Comment: Man, what is it about WiX questions? I swear I've never seem more ornery answers from any other part of SO. "RTFM" is such a common answer, it's almost like, maybe there's something wrong with manual -_- haha

Answer (score 1):

You can go through this [link](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_registrysearch.htm)

Use this code

```
<Property Id="INSTALL_SERVICE">
   <RegistrySearch Id="ServiceSearch" Name="ServiceName" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\CompanyName\[ProductCode]\FeatureDetails" Type="raw" />
</Property>
```

Also you are new to WIX, so please go through this links

- [WIX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/main.htm)
- [Tutorials](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/)

Comment: hi sunil thanks for your comment, but i am unable to see the value

Comment: A little late in the day but specifying a type of raw for registrysearch will simply return #1 if the search finds the key