# Version check way in WiX Installer

Tags: .net, wix

I added DetectCondition to "~.wxs" as below.

<ExePackage Id="NET480_INSTALL"
...

DetectCondition="(Netfx4FullVersion="**4.8.04115**") AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR (Netfx4x64FullVersion="**4.8.04115**"))"

But, I'm wondering if the 4.8.04115 is proper version for comparison input because the below .net framework 4.8 has different versions like both "File version" (4.8.4115.0) and "Product version" (4.8.04115.00) in properties as the below picture.

Would you please let me know which version info is proper one to be input with "Netfx4FullVersion="  ?

[ndp48-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zibQV.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that Netfx4FullVersion supports .net framework 4.8 - for example it will not work with .net 5. And it's a big problem.

Easiest way is to [write custom action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54144994/how-to-create-custom-actions-in-c-sharp-and-bind-it-on-a-wix-setup-project) that will [check version via registry](https://smartdoc.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205232308-How-to-check-your-NET-Framework-version) and [write result to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503593/custom-action-in-wix-to-manipulate-string-and-set-property). But you'll get only 4.8. This key will not work with .net 5. So I'll recommend to check both via custom action, because, for example, if .net 5 is installed you don't need to install 4.8 additionally. [Here you can find my answer how to do it for .net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58930065/check-if-netcore-is-installed-using-customaction-with-wix/62679569#62679569). It's the same as .net 5.

As option you can [check this key using wix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388554/read-registry-value-in-wix). Also not valid for .net 5.